# Lost my "Artists" field in iTunes

Tags: itunes

Most of my old CDs that I'm adding to my iPod touch 4th generation are compilations, so I have to add in the details my hand. I accidentally got rid of the "Artists" column in iTunes, which made it nice if I wanted to sort by artist.

How do I get that field back, and do I have to re-enter each artist for several hundred songs by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the column headings and select Artist to add the column back.

[image]

You won't need to re-enter information for the songs since the information will not have been deleted.